# SEC_E_ALGORITHM_MISMATCH (0x80090331) - The client and server cannot communicate, because they d not possess a common algorithm

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using a python client to connect to C++ server over https. However when a client tries to download some file from the server I get a error reported by the server as "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do  not possess a common algorithm."

The client and the server are on the same machine. The server uses the following command to create a pem file:

```
openssl.exe"  req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -days 9999 -nodes -x509 \
    -keyout etc\\filestore.pem -out etc\\filestore.pem
```

What have I tried ?

1. I have imported the pem file into the certificates folder
2. I enabled SSL2,SSL3,TL1.0,TLS 1.1,TLS1.2 in the registry

There is a url that gets generated in the server. I pasted this url in the chrome browser. Where I got a warning like:

[image]

Comment: What is the server's DNS name, and what web server is powering it (is that an old IIS box)? SSLv3 is a bad idea. Loren Weith showed it was defective over a decade ago in [Differences Between SSLv2, SSLv3, and TLS](http://yaksman.org/~lweith/ssl.pdf). Many folks did not really listen, and then we got POODLE in 2014. What more is needed to stop using it?

Comment: @jww We are not using a webserver . We have written our server which imitates the https protocol . The server DNS is just a local host service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve the issue . SSLScan tool came to my rescue . SSLScan --no-failed  port> gave me the list of supported ciphers that the server supported . On the client side I am using curl library calls to download the file . What I did was

```
setOpt(new curlpp::options::SslCipherList("AES256-SHA"));
```

which set the cipher that my server was supporting .

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today, too.
I have resolved it.
It's because your client does not support the SSL3.0 algorithms your server uses.
Just change your serverside code from:

```
SSLv3_server_method()
```

to:

```
SSLv23_server_method()
```